# UILabel unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when updating from outside of class

Tags: swift, null, uilabel

I am trying to update temperatureLabel in my ViewController.swift file. Whenever I assign a value to it from my Weather class file, it resolves the error:

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

However, if I assign it a value in viewdidload of the ViewController.swift file, the label updates fine. Please help!

```
class Weather{
var city = ""
var lat = ""
var long = ""
var currentTemp = 0
var currentCondition: String?

var dayOneName: String?
var dayTwoName: String?
var dayThreeName: String?

var dayOneCondition: String?
var dayTwoCondition: String?
var dayThreeCondition: String?

var mainVC: ViewController!


func getWeatherFromAPI(){
    let urlString = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/<removed key>/(\self.lat),\(self.long)"
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
            do {
                let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]

                    let currentConditions = parsedData["currently"] as! [String:Any]
                    let temp = currentConditions["temperature"] as! Int!
                    self.currentTemp = temp!
                    print(self.currentTemp)//returns expected value

                    self.mainVC.temperatureLabel.text = "\(self.currentTemp)" //fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }

    }).resume()
}//end of getWeatherFromAPI
}
```

and here is the ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var conditionImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var mainConditionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mainCityLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var temperatureLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var dayOneLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dayTwoLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dayThreeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dayOneConditionImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var dayTwoConditionImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var dayThreeConditionImage: UIImageView!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var currentLocation = Weather()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

        if (error != nil){
            self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
            return
        }

        if (placemarks?.count)! > 0{
            let pm = (placemarks?[0])! as CLPlacemark
            self.locationInfo(placemark: pm)
        }
        else{
            print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
        }
    })
}
func locationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark?){
    if let containsPlacemark = placemark{
        //stop updating location to save battery life
        //locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        if containsPlacemark.locality != nil{
            let locality = containsPlacemark.locality
            let location = self.locationManager.location
            let lat = String(describing: location!.coordinate.latitude)
            let long = String(describing: location! .coordinate.latitude)

            self.currentLocation.city = locality!
            self.currentLocation.lat = lat
            self.currentLocation.long = long

            self.currentLocation.getWeatherFromAPI()
        }
        else{
            _ = ""
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your viewDidLoad

```
 self.temperatureLabel.text=Weather.getWeatherFromAPI()
```

and in your weather class delete:

```
  self.mainVC.temperatureLabel.text = "\(self.currentTemp)"
```

The other thing you should do is to make func getWeatherFromAPI() to return a string

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse! I've tried this before and it just hangs on the launch screen. Im not sure if thats because it creates a new instance of ViewController which in my VC creates an instance of Weather which would seem to just continually loop through the same results?

Comment: can you add self.temperatureLabel.delegate = self in your viewDidLoad

Comment: Value of type 'UILabel' has no member 'delegate'

Comment: Because you have to put this class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate

Comment: I, unfortunately, am getting the same errors after adding that

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var mainVC: ViewController = ViewController()
```

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse! I've tried this before and it just hangs on the launch screen. Im not sure if thats because it creates a new instance of ViewController which in my VC creates an instance of Weather which would seem to just continually loop through the same results?

Comment: Did you pass the instance of ViewController to the Weather instance?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the `mainVC` with the current instance of `ViewController`.

```
class ViewController... {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        self.currentLocation.mainVC = self
    }
}
```